# Mini Split condensate pump to condensate drain

Tags: plumbing, hvac, air-conditioning

I'm working out the details of my Mini split.

I know by code I have to have it connected to a 3/4" condensate line going outside.  The Mini Split's air handler is located on an inside room where I'm forced to use a condensate pump.  I currently have the condensate pump pushing out water directly via a clear hose 3/8ic hose and it's fine for now, but I want it to code.

My initial idea is to have a PVC with an elbow inside the attic to outside, and put a 3/8" bib on the end closest to the air handler and let it pump away and make sure there is a downward incline in the hose to make sure the water runs out of the house.  Is this the best way? do I need a tee fitting like my whole home AC unit (  straight pipe with some sort of T fitting with no pipe on the top, and it continues out the house )?

I'm looking at doing something similar to this: https://youtu.be/HJwFgi3D-6g?t=58  at the 58 second mark

Just trying to get an idea of what I need to do.  Seems straight forward, but I know that nothing is ever what it seems when you don't know what you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about code, but I don't see anything wrong with what's shown in the video. You need a 3/4" MPT threaded to 3/8" barb fitting with a small hose clamp, or a 3/4" slip x 3/8" barb fitting to connect the PVC to your hose. The T on your house A/C is probably there to provide an overflow in case the exit on the outside gets obstructed, either by dirt or by ice. Obviously you want it in a place that minimizes damage should it overflow there...

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I didn't add that overflow part, but the 3/4 to a threaded brass barb fitting, attached the hose to the pipe, and clamped it down.